# custom firefox profile in selenium causes addons to be incompatible

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-rc, gallio, wap

Now this is tricky. I am trying to do WAP testing using firefox and selenium. For that I've created a custom profile and installed a plugin called modify headers. When I launch the profile manually, the addon works fine. But, when I use it with Selenium RC, then, Firefox disables the plugin, saying that it is incompatible with Firefox 3.6.6. This is ridiculous.If I open the same firefox profile manually, the plugin works fine. Also, when I update plugin (in the profile launched by ff),I installs a compatibility patch and works fine after restarting FF. But, when I close firefox and launch the same profile from selenium, it again gives the same problem. Please help, a lot of my test cases are based on WAP. You can also suggest alternatives to this plugin.

Thanks and Regards
Vamyip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try disabling extension compatibility checking in Firefox (using your Selenium profile):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.checkCompatibility

1. Type about:config in the address bar and hit enter
2. Click "I'll be careful".
3. Right-click anywhere on the list.
4. Select New > Boolean
5. Enter "extensions.checkCompatibility.3.6" as the preference name
6. Select false

Comment: Hello Aaron, really thank you for the answer. The trick worked. I had prepared a workaround for the problem. I had set the user agent string in the custom profile to that of a mobile device. But, your trick will help me with a lot of other addons which I couldn't use earlier

Answer (score 2):

I've had a few situations where I thought I was loading FireFox 3.6.x, but it was actually opening a newer version of Firefox (v16) installed on the machine. Because the profiles are stored in different places, it wasn't actually opening the profile I thought it was.

I thought I'd mention it just in case it explains varmyip's issue for other folks experiencing the same issue.